# Regex match >123 and reject >>123

Tags: regex

I'm writing a class to parse a truly small markdown-like language for a project.
The syntax says that `>123` or `>Text` are blockquotes, while `>>123` (numeric only) is a special kind of link.

Problem is, my regex matches both >123 and >>123. I'm trying to build 2 expressions that match only its own syntax and rejects the other.

To match only the special link, capturing number:

```
/>>(\d+)/gi

>>123      [MATCH]
>>Text     [NO MATCH]
>123       [NO MATCH]
>Text      [NO MATCH]

Works like it should.
```

To match only the blockquote, capturing the text/number:

```
/[^>]>(.*)/gi
>>123     [NO MATCH - I don't know why!]
>>Text    [MATCH - Shouldn't]
>123      [MATCH - OK]
>Text     [MATCH - OK]

Doesn't works.
```

The expected result for the last example:

```
>>123    [NO MATCH]
>>Text   [NO MATCH]
>123     [MATCH]
>Text    [MATCH]
```

How can I build it to ignore the double > character and capture the alphanumerical text?

Comment: Are `>` or `>>` always at the start of the line (or not)? What language do you use?

Comment: Yes, it can only be used on a newline, at the beginning. I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the trick?

```
(?<=[^>]>)[^>]+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/yK5aO4/1

If you only care about matching the expression and not getting the alphanumeric part, you can remove the lookbehind and end up with this: `[^>]>[^>]+\b`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did worked as a charm! As soon I can vote it as the answer, I will (still more 5 minutes before I can close the question)

Comment: OP said its a markup language so syntax might be strict. Should be an easy fix to allow spaces if necessary but I'm not able to take a look at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python or PHP, you can add a lookbehind to check what happens before `>`. Example, that forbids an other `>` before `>`:

```
(?<!<)<
```

where `(?<!...)` is the negative lookbehind assertion that means "not preceded by" (the content matched by the subpattern in a lookbehind (or a lookahead) are not returned in a whole match result. They are only checks.)

If `>` must start at the beginning of a line, you don't need a lookbehind, you can only use an anchors (that marks the position of the newline):

```
^>[0-9]+
```

(use the `re.MULTILINE` or `re.M` flag with Python or the `m` modifier with PHP)

With these element you will be able to write your own pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, regex flags are really not my forte, I'll keep them in mind! As I'm still thinking about parsing the markup using javascript when available (I don't think parsing it server-side will really affect the perfomance, but it should be a nice fail-safe way to be able to parse it in both sides) I'll avoid using language-specific functions, but I'm noting it down if I change my mind about client-side parsing.

Comment: @AndreScutieri: the `m` modifier exists in javascript too. Thinking that you can build a regex independently of a language is an urban legend. Each language has its own regex syntax and behavior particularities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with start anchor and `multiline` (m) flag:

```
'/^>([^>]\S*)/'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS3cW4/3)

`[^>]` is there to make sure we don't match `>>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This regex is really clever, and I really should study more about regex flags.

Comment: Yes and it ii simpler regex as well that will work in languages where lookbehind isn't supported like Javascript.